# Mysql joining table data, needing to drag out data from both in 1 query

Tags: php, mysql, xml

So i am generating a XML file based on data from mysql tables but need to be able to get the data i want from 2 tables using my query and unsure how to do this. details are as follows:

```
TABLE: store_locations
===================================
store_location_id
country
latitude
longitude
===================================

TABLE: store_locations_descriptions
===================================
store_location_id
name
description
city
===================================
```

PHP Function:

```
// Function to generate XML file based on store data from database
function fn_store_locator_generate_xml(){
    $qur = db_get_field("JOIN QUERY WANTED HERE");
    $ans=mysql_query($qur);
    $output.= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<kml xmlns=\"http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2\">
<Document>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ans))
    {
      $output.="<name>".$row['name']."</name>";
      $output.="<description>".$row['description']."</surname>";
      $output.="<Placemark>";
      $output.="<name>".$row['name']."</name>";
      $output.="<Snippet>".$row['description']."</Snippet>";
      $output.="<description>".$row['description']."</description>";
      $output.="<Point>";
      $output.="<coordinates>".$row['latitude'].",".$row['longitude']."</coordinates>";
      $output.="</Point>";
      $output.="</Placemark>";
      $output.="</person>";
    } 
    $output.="</Document>";

    $file_name = "galleries.xml";
    $file_pointer = fopen($file_name, "w+");
    fwrite($file_pointer, "$output");
    fclose($file_pointer);
}
// generate the XML file
fn_store_locator_generate_xml();
```

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need a join. I'm assuming you have 1 to 1 relationship between these tables.

```
select s.store_location_id,
    s.country,
    s.latitude,
    s.longitude,
    d.name,
    d.description,
    d.city
from store_locations s
    join store_locations_descriptions d
    on s.store_location_id = d.store_location_id
```

You should certainly look into how joins work:
http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php

Comment: i seem to be getting Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/oneline/public_html/artisan/dev/addons/store_locator/func.php on line 128

and output is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document></Document>

Comment: Do you have access to try to execute the query directly against the DB? Through mysql client of phpmyadmin or something?

Comment: i run the query and get results back as expected, unsure why its not passing to the xml file - could be the mysql_fetch_array issue

Comment: I've made some assumptions, have you connected to the DB and selected a schema using `mysql_select_db`? Also I don't know what your `db_get_field` does - `$qur` should just be the sql above.

Comment: im looking into it at the moment, thanks for the solution on selecting data though :)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM store_locations JOIN store_locations_descriptions, but you should look at mysql join tutorial, joins are essential in manipulating data from databases for example: [mysql join tutorial](http://phpweby.com/tutorials/mysql/32)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sl.country, sl.latitude, sl.longitude, sld.name, sld.description, sld.city
FROM store_locations sl
JOIN store_location_descriptions sld
ON sl.store_location_id=sld.store_location_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select s.foo sd.foo
from store_locations s
join store_locations_descriptions sd
on s.store_location_id = sd.store_location_id
```